# Get session set in Django Rest Framwork in Django Channels

Tags: django-channels

I have a REST API which uses Django Rest Framework, so what i am trying to achieve is:

- When a user makes a request to the API, set the session. This session
  contains a random string.
- After session is set in DRF request, retrieve the session in Django channels and when user connects, send him back thru Websocket.

But i am unable to get the session in Django channels.

I can't attach the code where i am setting the key in the session because it is huge code. I just attach a simple line:

```
request.session['random_key'] = 'somerandomkey'
```

This is my django channels code:

This is my channels code:

```
def connect(self):
    # Don't let anybody 
    if self.scope['session'].get('random_key'):  # Not working, i am not getting the random_key
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
           self.scope['session'].get('random_key'),
           self.channel_name)
        self.accept()
```

**BUT!** When i make a request to the API, and i set a session, then this session set is not available in the session in channels. If i set the session in "normal" Django request, it exists in Django channels sessions. So the problem is with Django Rest Framework, i am not getting the sessions set in Django Rest Framework into channels scope.

Comment: Did you add the session middleware? check out this page in the docs https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/sessions.html

Comment: You should repost the question as a DRF question then and show your DRF session settings